# How to use joinwith in yii2 framework

Tags: yii2-advanced-app

I have created a curd called 'Status' and it is working properly. I have created a new Model(with table) called `relation(id, status_id, user_id)`.

Now I want to join `relation` table to `Status` while showing records with some custom condition.

How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

To make connection between two tables with foreign key create function in model Relation like this.

```
public function getStatus()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Status::className(),['id'=>'status_id']);
}
```

To access value of status from relation model object, you can like this.

```
$relation->status->name_of_attribute;
```

$relation one object from *Relation* model.

Comment: I want to update `status` curd(records) which are showing on `/backend/web/status/index` url. How to use above in `StatusSearch` Model?

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you want. Check documentation first. This is about making relations [link](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#relational-data)